# Is new Multi-Monitor feature on 12.04 working with nvidia binary driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 12.04

I still can't use Multi-Monitor on 12.04 with nvidia binary driver. Anyone has a workaround for this ?

I know i can use nvidia settings using twinview but this has several disadvantages (e.g. some apps see single big screen e.g. vnc server).

**EDIT:**

seems like it's not possible since nvidia binary driver does not support anything above xrand 1.1

Comment: New nvidia 302 drivers do support xrandr 1.3 so there is a hope for good support for the multimonitor in future

Answer (score 0):

Could you try logging out then logging back in using Ubuntu/Unity 2D (this is an option at the login screen when you click on the gear icon).

Original suggestion found here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1945891